Static smp_affinity on linux host
I have a Intel i210 network card which support 4 combined fifo channels. I want to spread irq handlers from these channels among first 4 cores on my system.
I've tried to add udev rule that will be triggered on ADD event from the kernel:
/etc/udev/rules.d/98-i210-network-card.rules:
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", DEVPATH=="/devices/...", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/spread-i210-irq-handlers.sh"

/usr/local/bin/spread-i210-irq-handlers.sh:
set -exuo pipefail
# spread IRQs across CPUs 0-3
proc_curr=0
proc_max=4
for irq_path in /sys/$DEVPATH/msi_irqs/*; do
  irq=$(basename $irq_path)
  echo $proc_curr > /proc/irq/$irq/smp_affinity_list
  proc_curr=$(( (proc_curr + 1) % proc_max ))
done

But the problem is that /proc/irq/$irq/smp_affinity_list file does not exist at this moment.
What is the right way to statically configure smp_affinity_list for some device?
